# CKEditor toolbar positioning to right side of content with floated image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor for content management.I want to position the toolbar to the right side of my page where i have floated image on left and the content on the right side.

Content has to wrap around the image and hence i am floating the image.

This is the only link i can found when i researched but that doesn't help me .

[CKEditor inline toolbar position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947989/ckeditor-inline-toolbar-position)

Can anyone please help?

Here's my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/n8WJ2/7/

HTML:

```
 <div class="fl">
    <img src="http://www.destination360.com/north-america/us/montana/images/s/great-falls.jpg" height="300" width="300" />
    </div>
<div>
    <div class="section-title">Section title</div>
<div id="editable">
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function () {
    var editArea = j('#editable');
    editArea.attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    CKEDITOR.inline(editArea.get(0), {}, '');


});
```

CSS:

```
.fl {
    float: left;
}

#editable {
    min-height: 300px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't be positioning your wrapper to the left. You also have extra `</div>` tags.

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="section-title">Section title</div>
<div id="editable">
</div>
```

And since your CKEditor has a margin (from the page margin), you should add a margin to your image.

```
.fl {
    float: left;
    margin: 40px;
}

#editable {
    min-height: 500px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8WJ2/8/

Comment: This works great. But my requirement is to have content in the right div along with the editable div. According to your solution, section title div comes out of the container.

Answer (score 0):

**CKEditor** do not allows you to configure the position of the toolbar, there are some workarounds like the one provided by josh.

But I think the best option is to create a container `div` for your image and editable content, so the CKeditor can adjust the bar to the best position.

[image: CKEditor]

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8WJ2/10/)**

#### HTML:

```
<div class="edit-container">
    <div id="editable" contenteditable="true">

    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.edit-container {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    min-height: 340px;
}

#editable {
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 340px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i want to wrap the content around the image and so this solution is not feasible to me

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that! So you want your image inside the editor area? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n8WJ2/11/ ?